# Ni idea de cómo plantear diagrama entidad relación

Tags: base-de-datos

de antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda porque no tengo idea de qué hacer. El problema planteado es el siguiente:

---

La unidad de cuidados intensivos neonatales (UCIN) es un lugar donde médicos altamente
capacitados brindan a bebés cuidados durante las 24 horas, en el caso de que haya nacido
prematuramente, con un defecto de nacimiento u otra complicación. El proyecto pretende verificar
in-situ dos variables globales:

1 La condición de operación de la tecnología biomédica, que incluye cunas e incubadoras
neonatales, monitores de signos vitales, ventiladores mecánicos, entre otros.
2 -Las características técnicas del área, incluyendo su flujo hospitalario y en donde se atienden
a los pacientes con dichas tecnologías, midiendo una serie de parámetros técnicos
ambientales y eléctricos que pueden incidir en la atención y recuperación del paciente.

El fin del proyecto es verificar el cumplimiento de los estándares internacionales de estas variables
en las UCIN tomadas como objetivo.

Su grupo de trabajo ha sido designado para realizar la etapa de análisis y diseño de la solución a
implementar.

Para lograr el objetivo se ha definido una lista de parámetros, estándares y variables a verificar, para
luego realizar el análisis de los datos. Las variables se listan a continuación:

1. Iluminación ambiental
2. Ruido
3. Temperatura
4. Humedad
5. Estado de los receptáculos eléctricos.
6. Inspección estandarizada de seguridad eléctrica.

Para realizar las inspecciones se han diseñado tres herramientas (Ver anexos A, B y C) que funcionan
de una manera típica: elementos a papel que se llenan en el lugar, luego, se digitalizan y finalmente
se guardan los datos en una plataforma para su posterior análisis. Este proceso tiene dos problemas
importantes:

1. El proceso de llenado, digitalización y guardado de información es lento.
2. El proceso de digitalización de la información aumenta la posibilidad de cometer algún error
   en los datos.

Por lo que el equipo ha optado por diseñar una aplicación compatible con dispositivos móviles para
que las mediciones se puedan registrar de manera digital en el momento y al finalizar la inspección
se pueda sincronizar fácilmente con un servidor central.

El desarrollo deberá basarse en el uso del patrón modelo vista controlador (MVC), que es un patrón
estructural que permite separar la información, la parte visual de la aplicación y la lógica que
gestiona las relaciones y eventos del sistema. Para este proyecto, la capa de enfoque será la capa
modelo, que está definida por el administrador de bases de datos y para el caso, se seleccionó como

### gestor SQL Server utilizando como modelo, el modelo relacional.

Aclaración: Los anexosen los que se habla (A,B, C) son simples formularios (muy extensos). En el primero se evalúan los parámetros ambientales; en el segundo receptáculos eléctricos y en el tercero verificación de seguridad eléctrica.

Hasta el momento esto es lo único que se me ocurre. Me he abstenido e usar cardinalidad porque dudo mucho que esté bien hecho. La forma en la que está planteado todo me dificulta imaginarme la solución:

[image: Hast ahora]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta no es del todo clara. Pusiste toda la declaracion de tu ejercicio y lo que intentaste, pero no queda claro donde tenes la duda. En que punto? no nos pidas revisar tu ejercicio, porque podemos tener distintos puntos de vista, y no tienen porque ser acorde a los de tu profesor.

Comment: Bienvenido al stacoverflow! Lo que dijo gbianchi tiene razón, todos tenemos puntos de vista diferente. Necesitas editar tu problema y poner los códigos que has hecho. Trata de comprender bien el problema que te está dificultando (consejo: recomiendo tener la idea de tomar ejemplos de UML)